# Kendo and MVC style templating

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, templates, kendo-ui

I'm trying to figure out how to get kendo UI to behave like MVC does.
when I render a template I want to pass in metadata with the model then generate the right output for the given model.

For example in MVC I would do this ...

```
//define a custom object.cshtml in editortemplates within views
@if (ViewData.TemplateInfo.TemplateDepth < 2)
{
    foreach (var prop in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties
        .Where(metadata => metadata.ShowForEdit && !metadata.IsComplexType && !ViewData.TemplateInfo.Visited(metadata)))
    { 
        <li>
            @Html.Label(prop.PropertyName)
            <div class="value">
                @Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName, prop.TemplateHint, new { @class = "k-input" })
            </div>
        </li>
    }
}

//In any view after defining the above
<ul>
   @html.EditorFor(m => m)
</ul>
```

This would spit out a list of controls that when edited and posted back to the server map back to the object and can be saved.
Those controls will have all the right attributes on them to handle hooking up validation and be defined as the correct types, so a boolean would be a checkbox and a string a textbox or textarea depending on metadata.

In kendo I would like to produce the same result so ...
Here's what I have so far:

I defined a template like this for rendering an editor for any arbitrary object ...

```
<script id="editor" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    # var meta = getType(data.type) #
    <h2><span class="k-sprite edit"></span> #: meta.DisplayName #: <span data-bind="text:ID">#: data.ID #</span> <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/close.png")" /></h2>
    <ul class="fieldList">
    # for(i in data) { #
        # var prop = meta.getProperty(i) #
        # if(prop != null && getTemplate(prop.Template) != null) { #
        <li>
            <label class="fieldLabel">#: prop.DisplayName  #</label>
            #= renderTemplate('editable' + prop.Template, data[prop.PropertyName]) #
        </li>
    # }} #
    </ul>
    <hr />
    <button class="k-button">Save</button>
</script>
```

I then defined individual templates based on the values I would find in prop.Template, this is either the .Net type name or the value of mvc's uihint attribute (the server computes this).

All good at the root editor level template but then within each field I have a model but no idea how to get the variable prop defined here which represents the metadata for that property on an object of that type so I can determine how to correctly render the controls.

Telerik support have suggested having the server generate an editor template per type using MVC but this feels wrong and defeats my objective here which is to have the app just ask for data after an initial load (mostly) just like MVC would do on the server.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will never work, reason:

Javascript and kendo have no concept of type, so how can metadata be a workable concept in that environment.

Lesson to learn here: 
Templating in js is not half what MVC allows us to do and never will be due to limitations in the language.

I worked around this by templating objects on the server then binding whole objects to kendo templates generated by razor in MVC.